# Can I pay to increase my Google App Scripts Quota Limits?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a very complex core banking system using MongoDB and Google Sheets, and we are hitting the Google Apps Script quota limits and getting timeouts daily. We are looking at optimizing where we can, but I need to know if there is a way that I can increase the limits somehow in the meantime (don't mind paying more).

I have looked at the Early Access Program, but it says that they aren't taking any more new members.

Any ways that I can increase the limits?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can

- If you have a look at the [Apps Script Quota information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), you will see that the limits depend on the type of account you have.
- If you have a free account, it means that most likely it is a `Customer Account`.
- You can upgrade to either `G Suite Basic`, `G Suite Business` or `G Suite Enterprise` - depending on how much you need to increase your quota and how much you are willing to pay.

See [here](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html) for more information about different accounts and pricing.